# OleDbException was unhandled: Syntax Error (missing operator) In Query Expression

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, oledb

I am new in creating an application using Visual Stuido 2010 C# and Microsft Access 2007. I am planning to create an application where the user can add data to the database(MS-Access). But I got an error stating that "**Syntax Error (missing operator) In Query Expression**". I really can't find what's the problem with my code.

This is my code in adding data to the database:

```
private void buttonSaveFuelLimit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\KKKKK\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Trial\Trial\gxi.accdb";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(MyConString);
        OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(MyConString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand com = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "insert into fuel_limit(fuel_limit_code, fuel_limit_description) values(?fuel_limit_code, ?fuel_limit_description)";
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?fuel_limit_code", OleDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?fuel_limit_description", OleDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters["?fuel_limit_code"].Value = textBoxFuelLimitCode.Text;
                command.Parameters["?fuel_limit_description"].Value = textBoxFuelLimitDesc.Text;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the screen shot of the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--- Edited answer ---
following will work

```
command.CommandText = "insert into fuel_limit(fuel_limit_code, fuel_limit_description) values(?, ?)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(new OleDbParameter("@fuel_limit_code",textBoxFuelLimitCode.Text));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(new OleDbParameter("@fuel_limit_desc", textBoxFuelLimitDesc.Text));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

--- old answer ---

here is the line that needs correction

```
command.CommandText = "insert into fuel_limit(fuel_limit_code, fuel_limit_description)";
//should ne
command.CommandText = "insert into fuel_limit(fuel_limit_code, fuel_limit_description) values(?,?)";
```

Comment: I already added the values in my query but there is a new error occured. What might be the problem of this. Thanks

Comment: Got error when I used your code (No overload for method 'AddWithValue' takes 1 arguments). But when I changed the 'AddWithValue' with 'Add' only it works perfectly. Is it okay to use 'Add' only? Thank you so much.

Comment: yes you can use Add also, you will get warning sometime because Add(paramName, value) is deprecated, but it will work correctly.

Comment: In using your code above, where can I specify the data type that I will input in my forms?

Comment: You can not, that's why it is deprecated, if you edit values(?,?) in your code, and use @ in adding params, it will work

Answer (score 4):

You need the values part of the insert into statement.

insert into fuel_limit (fuel_limit_code, fuel_limit_description) values (?fuel_limit_code, ?fuel_limit_description)

Also, it looks like your you need to use the description parameter when setting the value in the line right above the ExecuteNonQuery statment.

Comment: Thanks for that. I already added the code but there is a new error occured. What do you think is wrong with my code?